# Install Anbox on Windows 11 (Ubuntu WSL)

Tags: windows, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I successfully installed Ubuntu WSL on Windows 11 using [this guide](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-run-google-play-store-android-apps-windows-11) without any issues. However, when I try to install Anbox following the [official website](https://docs.anbox.io/userguide/install.html), I keep getting errors like these:

```
error: cannot communicate with server: Post http://localhost/v2/snaps/anbox: dial unix /run/snapd.socket: connect: no such file or directory
```

and

```
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate. Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
```

Then I tried this solution:

```
# This part adds the Microsoft repository to install dotnet-runtime, which you need for `systemd-genie`
wget https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb -O packages-microsoft-prod.deb
sudo dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb
rm packages-microsoft-prod.deb
# This part installs the .NET runtime
sudo apt-get update; \
  sudo apt-get install -y apt-transport-https && \
  sudo apt-get update && \
  sudo apt-get install -y aspnetcore-runtime-6.0
# This part adds the transdebian repository, which contains systemd-genie
wget -O /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/wsl-transdebian.gpg https://arkane-systems.github.io/wsl-transdebian/apt/wsl-transdebian.gpg

chmod a+r /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/wsl-transdebian.gpg

cat << EOF > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wsl-transdebian.list
deb https://arkane-systems.github.io/wsl-transdebian/apt/ $(lsb_release -cs) main
deb-src https://arkane-systems.github.io/wsl-transdebian/apt/ $(lsb_release -cs) main
EOF
#This part installs systemd-genie
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -y systemd-genie
# This part adds a script to `~/.profile` to automatically start genie every time you start up bash.
echo "# Are we in the bottle?
if [[ ! -v INSIDE_GENIE ]]; then
  read -t 3 -p 'yn? * Preparing to enter genie bottle (in 3s); abort? ' yn
  echo

  if [[ $yn != y ]]; then
    echo 'Starting genie:'
    exec /usr/bin/genie -s
  fi
fi
" >> ~/.profile
# Restart bash
exec bash
```

The next time I launched Ubuntu WSL I got this before running any command:

```
-bash: /root/.profile: line 15: conditional binary operator expected
-bash: /root/.profile: line 15: syntax error near `y'
-bash: /root/.profile: line 15: `  if [[  != y ]]; then'
```

And when I try to follow the steps from [Anbox](https://docs.anbox.io/userguide/install.html) I get these:

```
/dev/binder$: command not found
-bash: /dev/ashmem: No such file or directory
$: command not found
```

What am I doing wrong?

PS: This question was originally posted to [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70550043/install-anbox-on-windows-11-ubuntu-wsl) but was forced closed.

PS: My technical background is extremely limited. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> My technical background is extremely limited

No worries, and that's actually useful information here.  It helps me at least *try* to provide an answer that's matched to your experience level.  That said, the reasons behind this *are* fairly technical, but you've done a great job of trying to work through some of them so far.

As I think you figured out, both of the first two errors you saw were because WSL does not support Systemd (and thus not Snaps).  This is perhaps one of the biggest challenges people run into when attempting to use it as a one-for-one replacement for a "real" Linux system.

Systemd is the "standard" initialization system for most Linux distributions, but WSL uses its own `/init` as the startup, and for good reasons that I won't go into here.

But that does mean that some software that expects Systemd just won't work on WSL without additional effort.  [Snaps](https://snapcraft.io) are a way of installing software into Linux that utilizes Systemd.

As the [Anbox installation guide](https://docs.anbox.io/userguide/install.html) mentions:

> To install Anbox your system need to support snaps. We do not officially support any other distribution method of Anbox at the moment but there are community made packages for various distributions (e.g. Arch Linux), but ...

There are workarounds for Systemd/Snap support on WSL, and Genie, which was your second attempt, is one of those.  That said, I *think* you are using some outdated instructions for installing Genie.  Check out [the Genie github](https://github.com/arkane-systems/genie) for the latest on that.

Based on the comments to my original answer here:

> @moyadin *This link I posted up windowscentral.com is for replacing Amazon's Store with Google's Store. I succeeded in this regard.

Wow -- I'm pretty impressed, since that's pretty dang technical ;-).  I originally thought you were referring to just using that guide to install WSL2.  I've skimmed through it now to get an understanding of what you've done.

If you have that running, then you are using an early (but modified) version of WSA (Windows Subsystem for Android), which as far as I can tell *should* be isolated, since it runs in a virtual machine like WSL2.  I'm probably not going to follow that particular guide myself, since it involves some fairly "beta" technology that isn't designed to be run on the "normal" version of Windows 11 just yet.  BUT, I'm very conservative when it comes to my system.

I might, on the other hand, try it out in a Windows 11 VM I have.

I spent some time yesterday attempting to install Anbox on WSL2, and I wasn't successful.  At the very least, you have to have:

- Systemd running to a better degree than I did
- As far as I can tell, you need to build your own kernel with support for the [Anbox `binder` and `ashmem` kernel modules](https://docs.anbox.io/userguide/install_kernel_modules.html).  I was, as far as I can tell, successful with this, but it did take two attempts to get it right.
- Set WSL2 to use your custom kernel (again, I did this successful and verified that the Anbox modules loaded properly).
- Install Anbox -- While I *was* able to install the Snap on WSL2, I was unsuccessful at actually running it, and I'm 95% sure that it's still due to Systemd issues.

  If I spent more time on it, I might be successful, but then I'd still have to do the next step in order to get to the Play Store ...
- Run a very complicated [script](https://github.com/geeks-r-us/anbox-playstore-installer/blob/master/install-playstore.sh).  It's ironically funny that I found this in the article [Anbox: How To Install Google Play Store And Enable ARM (libhoudini) Support, The Easy Way](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/07/anbox-how-to-install-google-play-store.html).  And after saying it's the easy way, they tell you (rightly):

  > Warning: never run a script you didn't write without knowing what it does. Before running this script, check out its code.
  > Unfortunately, understanding what that script is doing requires a *high* degree of Linux knowledge.

> But if it requires that much extensive work for Anbox then I will just disregard the whole thing.

I'm going to say that's the right choice.  My recommendation would be (a) stick with what you have running (b) it probably is as good or better than (and just as secure as) the Anbox solution.

> My end goal is to download Android apps in an isolated environment where the apps can't access everything (Like those downloaded from Microsoft Store for example) and Android x86 on VMware is the option I am currently using.

Well, if you do have the WSA option working that Windows Central documented, then that's most likely just as safe.  I'm sure that Microsoft will release more architecture information on WSA as they get closer to launch, but they have said it runs in a VM.  I'm guessing it is very similar to WSL2 in its architecture.

What we *really* are waiting for is WSA to be *released* by Microsoft.  Then, hopefully, we'll have some better options (although still unsupported) for using the Google Play Store.

Comment: You really did simply things nicely. Thank you so much.

I am aware of both Android x86 and Bluestacks. However I like the idea of launching an enclosed system like Anbox to install apps that are available on Microsoft Store but I have no idea what it has access to and when it does. I know I can do that with VMWare or the native virtual machine software on Windows but it is so much nicer to have it right in the start menu.

It slipped my mind but does Play Store offer this "enclosed" system like Anbox? Because if it does then I already have that. Thanks again.

Comment: @moyadin Is there a guide you are looking at?  I did some more digging to see what it might take to install Anbox on WSL, and even if you get it running, it doesn't have any access to the Play Store without some *extensive* additional work.  What you really want, I believe, is the upcoming Windows 11 feature that will [allow you to run Android apps](https://blogs.windows.com/windows-insider/2021/10/20/introducing-android-apps-on-windows-11-to-windows-insiders/) directly on the Windows 11 Desktop.  It will utilize the Amazon App Store  (also Android-based) rather than the Play Store, though.

Comment: This link I posted up https://www.windowscentral.com/how-run-google-play-store-android-apps-windows-11 is for replacing Amazon's Store with Google's Store. I succeeded in this regard. But if it requires that much extensive work for Anbox then I will just disregard the whole thing.
My end goal is to download Android apps in an isolated environment where the apps can't access everything (Like those downloaded from Microsoft Store for example) and Android x86 on VMware is the option I am currently using. I  just thought with Anbox I won't need to launch VMware and can launch apps like Play Store

Comment: If your recommendation is to keep using Android x86 on VMware as the most non-technical solution then maybe I should be content with it. It isn't too inconvenient anyway.